# Ruby on Rails - export user data to csv - button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-csv

Since I ended up using a csv method and not a json method I thought it might be a good Idea to change the question name and remove the part with the json if other people might have the same problem someday.

Update: I've tried using [this](http://techinpink.com/2016/08/29/exporting-records-to-csv-in-rails/) as a way to export data.

In my controller I have the following:

```
def profile
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user_posts = @user.posts.order('created_at DESC')

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @user.csv, filename: "userinfo-#{Date.today}.csv" }
end
```

end

In my view :

```
<p><%= link_to("Generate Report", user_path(@user, format: :csv), class: "btn btn-success",) %></p>
```

In my user.rb :

```
def csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |item|
        csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Update 2: Managed to fix it myself, I was using a wrong csv method in my Controller. Replacing it with the following :

```
def csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << %w{ user_id user_username user_email }
      csv << [ self.id, self.username, self.email]
    end
  end
```

works like a charm.

Best regards

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, updated it.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the button? The controller action? A downloadable document? Or?

Comment: I am asking for the controller action as well as the downloadable document.

Comment: Ah, that's a potentially broad question then. Did you look [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)?